# My game I made in Java is linking two sprites for some reason?

Tags: java, graphics2d

Well I made this game in java and when you shoot a bullet it moves the gun and the bullet. Here is the block of code where the problem is I think:

```
case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        Point2D currentGunPos = sGun.position();
        sBullet[bulletNum].setAlive(true);
        sBullet[bulletNum].setPosition(sGun.position());
        sBullet[bulletNum].setVelocity(new Point2D(-5,0));
        bulletNum++;
```

Why does it move the gun too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone the gun's position object, before calling the setPosition method on the bullet.

```
Point2D currentGunPos = (Point2D)sGun.position().clone();
sBullet[bulletNum].setPosition(currentGunPos);
```

Comment: Yep.  The reason for the error is when you set the bullet's position with the gun's position, if you move the bullet, you change the gun's position since both of their positions are represented by the very same Point2D object.  MBFG's solution guarantees that the gun and bullet use different Point2D objects to represent their positions, and so changing the state of one will not change the state of the other.

Comment: You could also design your own class similar to Point2D, but make it immutable (so all operations return a new instance). That way you would avoid future problems of this kind.

Comment: Or the `setPosition()` method could clone the parameter object (or simply use `myPosition.setPosition(pos)` or something like this), or the `position()` method could already return a clone.